# Can someone help me check my work for Calc 4?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I made a cup of tea with initial $T(0)=212F$ in my house at constant $A(0)=68F$. The tea took 18 minutes to drop $T(1)=135F$. Too slow! I placed the tea outside where $A(2)=35F$. Compute the tea’s $T$ after another 18-minute wait.

I used the formula: $$T(t)=A+(T(0)-A)e^{-kt}$$
where $t$=time, $A$=surrounding temp, $T(0)$=initial temp
$k$=constant

I plugged in for what I read in the first two sentences of the problem. I got:
$$ T(0)=212F, A(0)=68F, T(t=18)=135F$$
So 
$$ 135=68+(212-68)e^{-18k}$$
$k=.04251$

But then, it said to "compute the tea’s T after another 18-minute wait."
I'm not sure if I did this correctly because t can equal to 36 or 18??
$$ T(36)=68+144e^{-.04251(36)}=212e^{-1.53036}=45.88904F$$
OR
$$ T(18)=212e^{-.76518}=98.63304F$$

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: the second time you start all over because conditions have changed so you should use $t=18$

Comment: So the final answer should be 98.63304F one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you place tea outside, the final result $$T_2(18)=35+(135-35)e^{-0.04251 \cdot 18} \approx 81.53 \ F$$ Basically, you use the same formula as in the first part but you have new surrounding temp and new initial temp. Constant $k$ stays the same.